# OSGi Fragment using Spring Integration Testing

Tags: java, spring, osgi, integration-testing, spring-dm

I am posting this question given I haven't found any relevant answer so far.
I could not figure out how to run integration tests using Spring-Dynamic Modules.

### Problem Definition

**Template Application**

- One OSGi bundle containing the business logic. Using Spring DM to export / reference some services
- One OSGi fragment for the Integration Tests. Tests should be able to inject helper test beans which are defined in the fragment Application Context (using xml files under META-INF/spring) as well as OSGi services exported (from the API bundle)

**Versions**

- OSGi 3.6
- Spring Framework 3.1.0
- Spring Dynamic Modules 1.2.1

### Question

- How can I run Integration Test which would be aware of the Spring Application Context and of the exposed OSGi services?
  Using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/context.xml" })` leads to a `FileNotFoundException` regarding context.xml, which exists...
  Debugging `XmlBeanDefinitionReader` confirmed my doubts: `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is trying to load the Application Context from its OSGi classpath, and cannot access my Bundle Resources.

How would you best solve this please?

I do appreciate your help in advance.

ps: I had a look at [Spring DM Test](http://docs.spring.io/osgi/docs/1.2.1/api/org/springframework/osgi/test/package-summary.html) but did not find anything relevant.

### Example

**Bundle Manifest**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: HelloWorldDM
Bundle-SymbolicName: HelloWorldDM
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 ContactDAO;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations;bundle-version="1.2.1"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: ch.xxx.test.contact
```

**Integration Test Fragment Manifest**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: HelloWorldTest
Bundle-SymbolicName: HelloWorldTest
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Fragment-Host: HelloWorldDM;bundle-version="1.0.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.junit4;bundle-version="4.8.1",
 org.springframework.spring-test;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 org.springframework.spring-context;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 org.springframework.spring-beans;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 org.springframework.osgi.test;bundle-version="1.2.1",
 org.springframework.spring-core;bundle-version="3.1.0"
```

**Fragment Application Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
  
  <bean class="org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotation.ServiceReferenceInjectionBeanPostProcessor"/>
  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
  
</beans>
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/context.xml" })
public class TestCase {
    
    private BitemporalityService bitemporalityService;

    @ServiceReference
    public void setBitemporalityService(BitemporalityService service) {
        this.bitemporalityService = service;
    }

    @Test
    public void dummy(){
        System.err.println("in Test: ");
        assertNotNull(bitemporalityService);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [pax exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Pax+Exam). It boots up an osgi container and runs your test in it. It is the defacto standard framework for osgi testing and is used in many open source projects for the osgi itests. See https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/karaf/itests

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also thought about it, but found it really complex for generic Integration Testing. Isn't there really any other solution? No Meta Spring-Junit Runner able to deal with the seperated OSGi classpaths? Thanks

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Pax exam is not that complicated though. The newest version even allows to test in process in many cases